# How to use an API to act like a network drive

Tags: api, http, get, fileapi

I'm not sure my post title was worded in the best way it can be.
Essentially, I have this API where I can GET files and resources from this http request. I'm looking to map it as a network drive where I can just browse all my files. The application that the API is from is call Home Access Plus, GitHub Here: https://github.com/techienickb/hap

Any help is much appreciated.
Apologies if my wording is wrong, i'm not sure what's the best way to explain it.

Comment: The easiest route for this is probably building a WebDAV server. (note that this is not very easy)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, the server it's connected to I believe already has the WebDAV. When I try to connect with my Cyberduck client it gives me a 405 error, failing to list contents of Directory.

Comment: This is a support question, not a programming question. I would suggest you take it up with whatever support channel 'Home Access Plus' has.